# Alert Dialog does not show when I try to pass useDisclosure variables to a child component function in Nextjs and Chakra

Tags: reactjs, next.js, modal-dialog, chakra-ui

When this runs, and I click on the button, the alert dialogue does not get displayed, so I was wondering how to fix this issue?

This is my simplified version of the parent code:

```
const {
    isOpen: isOpen3,
    onOpen: onOpen3,
    onClose: onClose3,
  } = useDisclosure();
StartupComponent(
     accessories[res.get("selectedAccessory")][1],
     lvl,
     startupName,
     String(document),
     isOpen3,
     onOpen3,
     onClose3,
     cancelRef
)
```

While this is my child component code.

The button when clicked though does not display the alert dialogue...

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
const StartupComponent = (
  img,
  level,
  name,
  id,
  isOpen,
  onOpen,
  onClose,
  cancelRef
) => {

  return (
    <Flex
      direction={"row"}
      alignItems={"center"}
      justifyContent={"center"}
      backgroundColor={"#303030"}
      width={"90%"}
      paddingTop={5}
      paddingBottom={5}
      paddingLeft={5}
      borderRadius={3}
      boxShadow={"0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"}
      _hover={{
        boxShadow: "0 5px 5px rgba(100,100,100,0.9)",
      }}
    >
      <AlertDialog
        isOpen={isOpen}
        leastDestructiveRef={cancelRef}
        onClose={onClose}
      >
        <AlertDialogOverlay>
          <AlertDialogContent>
            <AlertDialogHeader fontSize="lg" fontWeight="bold">
              Delete {name}
            </AlertDialogHeader>

            <AlertDialogBody>
              Are you sure you want to delete {name}? You can't undo this action
              afterwards.
            </AlertDialogBody>

            <AlertDialogFooter>
              <Button ref={cancelRef} onClick={onClose}>
                Cancel
              </Button>
              <Button
                colorScheme="red"
                onClick={() => {
                  deleteIt();
                  onClose();
                }}
                ml={3}
              >
                Stop Timer
              </Button>
            </AlertDialogFooter>
          </AlertDialogContent>
        </AlertDialogOverlay>
      </AlertDialog>
      
      <Tooltip label={"Delete " + name + "..."} aria-label="A tooltip">
        <Button
          position={"absolute"}
          right={"28vw"}
          onClick={onOpen}
          colorScheme={"transparent"}
        >
          <Image
            src={"/assets/trash.png"}
            alt={"Gloppa menu"}
            width={35}
            height={35}
          />
        </Button>
      </Tooltip>
    </Flex>
  );
};
```